# Response Mode => Form_post

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, openid-connect

Is there a way to set response mode to form post instead of fragments or query string in angular-oauth2-oidc component for implicit flow?

Comment: Is your authentication request coming from a server? Or from code running in a browser? If it's in a browser, then you can't use a form post, as there's no server to post back to.

Comment: There seems to be a way, but it is not clear if it works: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/120